# How to set Gravity of Gridview?

Tags: android

How to set gravity of gridview, i used the following code for that but this code is not working.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <GridView 
         android:id="@+id/grdviewmainmenu" 
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
         android:horizontalSpacing="17dip" 
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         android:columnWidth="80dip" 
         android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
         android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as a parent. will perfectly work...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe changing `android:gravity="center"` to `android:layout_gravity="center"` will do the job? Actually, what do you mean by "this code is not working"?

Comment: Maybe any screens? How does it look with this code? What you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

u use   android:layout_gravity="center"